# GCC 7.1.1 RISCV compilation (link) failures, incompatible ABI

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, toolchain, riscv

I'm having difficulty doing basic compilation & link for RISCV on the latest GCC for RISCV on a windows 7-64bit platform.

Tools installed: 7.1.1-2-20170912-2255 gotten from https://github.com/gnu-mcu-eclipse/riscv-none-gcc/releases/

Platform:  Windows 7, 64 bit, no cygwin

Program:

```
#include <stdint.h>

int32_t iBlahblah;
int main (void)
{
    while(1)
        iBlahblah++;
    return 0;
}
```

Command line:

```
"c:\Program Files\GNU MCU Eclipse\RISC-V Embedded GCC\7.1.1-2-20170912-2255\bin\riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc.exe" -c hello.c -o hello  -march=rv32imac -mabi=ilp32  -Os 
"c:\Program Files\GNU MCU Eclipse\RISC-V Embedded GCC\7.1.1-2-20170912-2255\bin\riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc.exe" -o hello.elf  -march=rv32imac -mabi=ilp32  -Os -Wl,-Map=hello.lst hello.o
```

Output:

```
c:/program files/gnu mcu eclipse/risc-v embedded gcc/7.1.1-2-20170912-2255/bin/../lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-elf/7.1.1/../../../../riscv64-unknown-elf/bin/ld.exe: hello.o: ABI is incompatible with that of the selected emulation:  target emulation `elf64-littleriscv' does not match `elf32-littleriscv'
c:/program files/gnu mcu eclipse/risc-v embedded gcc/7.1.1-2-20170912-2255/bin/../lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-elf/7.1.1/../../../../riscv64-unknown-elf/bin/ld.exe: failed to merge target specific data of file hello.o
c:/program files/gnu mcu eclipse/risc-v embedded gcc/7.1.1-2-20170912-2255/bin/../lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-elf/7.1.1/../../../../riscv64-unknown-elf/lib/rv32imac/ilp32\libg.a(lib_a-exit.o): In function `.L0 ':  exit.c:(.text.exit+0x1e): undefined reference to `_exit'
c:/program files/gnu mcu eclipse/risc-v embedded gcc/7.1.1-2-20170912-2255/bin/../lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-elf/7.1.1/../../../../riscv64-unknown-elf/bin/ld.exe: hello.elf(.text): relocation "iBlahblah+0x0 (type R_RISCV_HI20)" goes out of range
c:/program files/gnu mcu eclipse/risc-v embedded gcc/7.1.1-2-20170912-2255/bin/../lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-elf/7.1.1/../../../../riscv64-unknown-elf/bin/ld.exe: hello.o: file class ELFCLASS64 incompatible with ELFCLASS32
c:/program files/gnu mcu eclipse/risc-v embedded gcc/7.1.1-2-20170912-2255/bin/../lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-elf/7.1.1/../../../../riscv64-unknown-elf/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: File in wrong format
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The big question is how do I resolve the "ABI is incompatible with that of the selected emulation"?  We can ignore the other issues regarding relocation, exit, etc. because my larger build environment takes care of that (it builds for many platforms, just not RISCV at the moment).

Comment: You use gcc for riscv64 and want it to compile in 32-bit mode. But this gcc will add c runtime libs for 64-bit mode into linking stage (add -v option to gcc to see additional crt files added by gcc) and this is wrong (32 bit elf and 64 bit elf objects can't be linked together). You should use gcc for 64-bit target with 64-bit mode; and gcc for 32-bit target with 32-bit mode (actually you need 32-bit crt; it may be included in your gcc, but it uses wrong version)

Comment: @osgx The documentation at https://gnu-mcu-eclipse.github.io/toolchain/riscv/install/ states that riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc.exe can target both 32bit and 64bit.   How do I hint to it to do the 32 bit libraries?

Comment: Use riscv32-unknown-elf-gcc.exe which will use correct path to 32-bit CRT. Compare output of `riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc.exe -v ...` vs `riscv32-unknown-elf-gcc.exe -v ...` to find exact directories with CRT.

Comment: Your gcc declares support for multilib to be capable of searching for 32-bit crt libs from riscv64-gcc: https://gnu-mcu-eclipse.github.io/toolchain/riscv/#multiple-libraries but something was wrong and it didn't select correct multilib dir. It can be useful to check actual `gcc/config/riscv/t-elf-multilib` https://github.com/riscv/riscv-gcc/blob/c95cdcae21de8dbb8a8ceb9c58b5f9560f0628ff/gcc/config/riscv/t-elf-multilib. https://gnu-mcu-eclipse.github.io/blog/2017/09/13/riscv-none-gcc-v7-1-1-2-20170912-released/ says "combinations of march/mabi are supported  .. not all of them have libraries."

Comment: @osgx I think the tool is mildly broken.   if I call via riscv-unknown-elf-ld.exe with the appropriate `-melf32lriscv` it doesn't have the issue.   I think that gcc.exe isn't passing the right stuff to ld.exe to tell it 'this is the ilp32 abi with the rv32imac instruction set'

Comment: Russ, please, post `-v` output and hello.o

Answer (score 0):

> riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc.exe -c hello.c -o hello  -march=rv32imac -mabi=ilp32  -Os

This part is wrong. Your gcc tolchain docs says https://gnu-mcu-eclipse.github.io/toolchain/riscv/

> riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc vs riscv32-unknown-elf-gcc
>   With lots of architectures and systems supported, GCC recommends prefixing the binaries with a unique tuple:
>
> ```
> <arch>-<vendor>-<os>-<libc/abi>-
> ```
>
> The current RISC-V prefixes for the bare metal toolchains are riscv64-unknown-elf- and riscv32-unknown-elf-.
>
> Well, don’t be confused by this unfortunate names. The 64 or 32 attached to the architecture  ... It does not mean either that the compiler produces 64-bits or 32-bits RISC-V binaries. Actually, the compilers produce both 32/64-bits binaries, based on -march and -mabi. The only difference are defaults, when the compiler are invoked without the -march and -mabi explicitly set on the command line.

Try to use riscv32-unknown-elf-gcc.exe for compiling programs for 32-bit riscv platform (with arch & abi having `r32` & `32` parts in their names), it should use correct 32-bit CRT files.

There is some support for  multilib, when riscv64 will search for 32-bit libs (https://gnu-mcu-eclipse.github.io/toolchain/riscv/#multiple-libraries, https://gnu-mcu-eclipse.github.io/blog/2017/09/13/riscv-none-gcc-v7-1-1-2-20170912-released/, https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Target-Fragment.html MULTILIB_OPTIONS), but something was wrong. Please, post `gcc -v .... -o your_program.bin`  results for riscv32 compiler, riscv64 compiler and several march/mabi combinations.

Comment: I can't find a pre-built riscv32-unknown-elf toolchain anywhere (and really don't have the time to go and build it myself).   The libraries are there in the standard install, it just seems that gcc.exe isn't invoking ld.exe correctly...or i'm not saying the right magic words to make it invoke ld.exe correctly